# Unable to load tensorflowJS model in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am trying to load a trained keras model into web browser using tensorflowjs.

I was able to convert the keras model to tensorflowjs model but unable to load model in chrome extension.

My background.js code to load model

```
async function app() {
    alert('Loading model..');
    model = await loadModel("model.json");
    alert('Sucessfully loaded model');
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
    alert("extension loaded");
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                       {file:"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"});

     app();
});
```

THe url "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js" is added in permissions key in manifest file.

When i try to laod the extension it fails givind message loadModel is not defined.

Any suggestions on fixing this issue?

Comment: You're specifying a URL, not a file. Only local file paths within the extension itself are allowed.

Comment: @wOxxOm: do you have a link to an example extension?

Answer (score 0):

> loadModel is not defined.

1 - Make sure that the script is loaded in the background process of the tabs

2 - You need to use `tf.loadModel()` instead of `loadModel()`